# CMD - How do I run a command twice in one line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I display both the host name and boot time?
The code I'm trying:

`systeminfo | find /i "host name" && "boot time"`

I know I could use

`systeminfo | find /i "host name"`

`systeminfo | find /i "boot time"`

but I really don't want to.

Basically I want the command to display the host name and boot time and ignore all else. How do I do that on one line? I know I'm missing something super simple here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518737/can-i-search-for-multiple-strings-in-one-find-command-in-batch-script

Comment: find is usually not a good tool to use, findstr is better. `systeminfo | findstr /i /c:"host name" /c:"boot time"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem before, and I may be able to help you out. If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way to display both the host name and boot time on one line, using a single prompt. In that case, the following command should do the trick, ignore the curly brackets of course:

```
{systeminfo | find /i "host name" & systeminfo | find /i "boot time"}
```

Using the `&` character will execute the two `systeminfo` commands sequentially and output the results on the same line.

I wish you the best of luck with your project. Let me know if I can help with anything else.

Comment: that's a terrible way to do because systeminfo is very slow and running it twice is even much less desirable

Comment: Not only are braces not valid characters in your provided command line, I agree with the above comment. At the very least, ```systeminfo | findstr /i /c:"host name" /c:"boot time"```, would be a vast improvement.

Comment: I had never considered that. Thank you, Compo, for your insight. I am new to using CMD in a professional setting, and although my initial suggestion achieves the desired outcome, as you and phuclv pointed out, it is terribly inefficient. I appreciate your feedback and the opportunity to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against running the slowest utility on Windows, `systeminfo.exe`, just to get this type of information.

You could, if you wish try to use a less intensive, and quicker utility, `net.exe`.

You should also try to not to expect utilities to output strings in a specific language.

Example:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "CN=" & For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%G In ('(%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe
 Stats Srv 2^>NUL ^|^| %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Stats Work^) ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ELV "."') Do If Not Defined CN (
    Set "CN=%%~nxG") Else For %%H In (%%G) Do (SetLocal EnabledelayedExpansion
    For %%I In ("!BT!") Do EndLocal & Set "BD=%%~I" & Set "BT=%%H")

If Defined CN Echo %CN% was booted on %BD% at %BT%& Pause
```